# How to copy a string to a 2D array in c

Tags: arrays, c, string, 2d

I want to create a c program that when the user enters some words like this: "some,words, in, c, proramming." the program save words in the string "str", then it creates Dynamically a 2D array and copies the words into the 2D array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

void freeMememory(int**array, int row){
    for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
        free(array[i]);
    free(array);
}

int lettersCount(char *arr){
    int space=0, letters=0;
        do{
        if(*arr !=' '&& *arr!='\t' && *arr!=','&& *arr!='.'){
          letters =letters+1;
        }
        ++arr;
        }while(*arr);

    return letters;
}

int wordCount(char *arr){
    int space=0, words=0;
    for(int i=0; arr[i]!='\0'; i++){
        if(arr[i] ==' '|| arr[i]=='\t'|| arr[i]=='\n'||arr[i]==','||arr[i]=='.'){
          space++;
        }
        if(space>0){
            words++;
            space=0;
        }
    }

    return words;
}
int main    (){
    char arr[100];
    int i, j, row, column;

    scanf("%[^\n]s", &arr);
    int *words = wordCount(arr);
    int *letters = lettersCount(arr);
    row=words;
    column=letters;

    int **ptr = (int **)malloc(row*column*sizeof(int));
    for(i=0;i<row;i++){ptr[i]=(int*)malloc(column*sizeof(int));}

    /*

    //how should I write here to copy only words from arr to ptr?
    like this:

    arr = "some words, two,three,four."
    
    ptr = {
       "some", "words", "two", "", "three", "four",
      }
     
    */

    freeMememory(ptr, row);
    return 0;}
```

So any ideas how to copy only the words from the string into the 2D array without copying (periods, spaces, cammas)?

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on. Staking up statements on one line really makes a mess of things.

Comment: What is going on with `ptr[i][j]=  ptr[i][j]`? I don't know what's going on in this code and I have a sneaking suspicion you've lost the plot as well. It's worth splitting this up into more functions, each of which has a very specific, extremely narrow purpose, like allocating or releasing that structure, and test that those work in isolation before integrating.

Comment: Tip: It'd help if you used things like `rows` or even `rowsCount` instead of the very misleading `row` variable.

Comment: `int *words = wordCount(arr);` assigns an `int` to an `int*`, which is invalid, and any effort to use that will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @tadman
ptr[i][j]=  ptr[i][j] ---> here I need the code to copy only the words from arr to ptr.

Comment: That code is the same as `x = x`.

Comment: @tadman I edited my code to be more understandable.

Comment: You should explain, what the code is intended to do, not letting people guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you might be looking for is [`strtok`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) from `<string.h>`. I will also replace `row` with `rows` and `column` with `columns` in the following code snippet, as suggested by [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189) in the comments.

```
/* no need to cast `malloc` */
char *ptr[rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    ptr[i] = malloc(columns);
    if (!token) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

const char *delims = " \t\n,.";

/* second argument are delimiters */
strcpy(ptr[0], strtok(arr, delims));
for (int i = 1; i < rows; ++i)
    strcpy(ptr[i], strtok(NULL, delims));
```

I would also suggest simplifying your functions. For example your `wordCount` function could probably be simplified to this:

```
int count_words(char *str, const char *delims)
{
    words = 1;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        if (strchr(delims, str[i]))
            ++words;
    return words;
}
```

The function `count_words` could then be called like this:

```
const char *delims = " \t\n,.";
int words = count_words(arr, delims);
```

Comment: Not sure, that seems a little harsh.

Comment: @tadman As I see it there are several mistakes here. 1) memory leaks by overwriting the malloc'ed `ptr[i]` 2) No `strcpy` to the destination

Comment: @4386427 You are absolutely right! I think I fixed both problems now, but let me know if there is more to improve.

Comment: Thanks to you both (tadman, Andy). It works.

Answer (score 1):

First notice that your code isn't using a 2D array. It's using an array of char-pointers that each point to a char-array. It's a different thing but it can be used in much the same way.

Below is an implementation that uses `strtok` to split the input string. Further, it uses `realloc` to make the array of char-pointers grow when a new word is found. Finally it uses a sentinel (i.e. `NULL`) to indicate end-of-words.

The code is pretty simple but the performance is poor.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char** split(const char* str)
{
    if (str == NULL) exit(1);

    // Copy input string as strtok changes its input    
    char* str_cpy = malloc(strlen(str) + 1);
    if (str_cpy == NULL) exit(1);
    strcpy(str_cpy, str);
    
    unsigned num_rows = 0;
    char** arr = NULL;

    // Get first token
    const char *delims = " \t\n,.";
    char* ptr = strtok(str_cpy, delims);
    while (ptr)
    {
        // Allocate one more row
        arr = realloc(arr, (num_rows + 1) * sizeof *arr);
        if (arr == NULL) exit(1);
        
        // Allocate memory for one more word
        arr[num_rows] = malloc(strlen(ptr) + 1);
        if (arr[num_rows] == NULL) exit(1);
        strcpy(arr[num_rows], ptr);
        ++num_rows;

        // Get next token
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delims);
    }

    // Add a sentinel to indicate end-of-words
    arr = realloc(arr, (num_rows + 1) * sizeof *arr);
    if (arr == NULL) exit(1);
    arr[num_rows] = NULL;
    
    free(str_cpy);    
    return arr;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char* str = "some,words, in,    c, programming.";
    char** arr = split(str);
    
    printf("Original string: %s\n", str);
    for (int i=0; arr[i] != NULL; ++i)
    {
        printf("Word[%d]: %s\n", i, arr[i]);
    }

    // Free array       
    for (int i=0; arr[i] != NULL; ++i)
    {
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    free(arr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```sh
Original string: some,words, in,    c, programming.
Word[0]: some
Word[1]: words
Word[2]: in
Word[3]: c
Word[4]: programming
```

Comment: Thanks, I have another question please, how to write a function to print the unique words in the array of string. e.g. arr[] = "this this this this is text" it prints only "is, text" ?

Comment: If you only want to save unique words, you must extend the `while (ptr)` loop and check if the current word is already in the array (and if it is, don't insert it again). For this `strcmp`is useful.